# Skip Runtime error inside loop cycle

Tags: ruby

I created this ruby script which basically search all the nodes/servers from an environment based on recipes from each server node. The issue is that it's failling if a node is stopped with Runtime error and it will get the next microservice according to *h[thread_id] << "ReadTimeout Error" next*

```
file = File.read("./#{srv}.json")
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)

h = {}
threads = []
service = data_hash.keys
service.each do |microservice|
threads << Thread.new do
thread_id = Thread.current.object_id.to_s(36)
 begin

 h[thread_id] = "#{microservice}"
 port = data_hash["#{microservice}"]['adport']
 h[thread_id] << "\nPort: #{port}\n"

 nodes = "knife search 'chef_environment:#{env} AND recipe:#{microservice}' -i 2>&1 | sed '1,2d'"
 node = %x[ #{nodes} ].split
 node.each do |n|
 h[thread_id] << "\n Node: #{n} \n"
 uri = URI("http://#{n}:#{port}/healthcheck?count=10")
 res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
 status = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  h[thread_id] << "#{res.code}"
  h[thread_id] << status
  h[thread_id] << res.message
end

rescue => e
  h[thread_id] << "ReadTimeout Error"
  next
end
end
end

threads.each do |thread|
  thread.join
end
ThreadsWait.all_waits(*threads)
h.values.join("\n")
```

How can I skip only that node and get the results for the other found nodes inside this loop before it moves to the next microservice.

Comment: Did you try running your script without using a thread for each service?

Comment: It was my mistake apparently it fails because of runtime error for nodes. Anyway I re-edit the question!